# How do I go about dynamically splitting a body of text into two even columns with plain Javascript (no JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already tried two approaches that don't seem to work: 1) I measured the total number of words and divided that by 2, but problems arise when there are really long words, and not all words are the same length, etc. 2) I measured the height in pixels of each character, the clientHeight of entire body of text, and divided the total height of the text by the height of one character to see how many lines go in one column and how many go in the other. This approach works really well except when an images, paragraphs, and other HTML tags need to be factored in.

I need to come up with a new approach that take images and other HTML tags into account, and I can only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (no JQuery, JSON, Ajax, etc). Let me know if you have an idea/algorithm! Thanks :)

Comment: Why exactly do you mean splitting a body of text? Like splitting it down the middle? Perhaps you can draw us a picture and show it to us visually? You can consider putting the top half in a div and the bottom half in another div and splitting it like that. Then it simply is a matter of generating content within those divs.

Comment: Like in this: http://www.washington.edu/lst/help/documentation/indesign/img/text_frame_column.jpg
So the body of text would be split into two even columns. And when I resize the browser, the text in the two columns would resize according to the browser size.

Comment: exactly like this in 2 columns, but i want to code it myself instead of using this: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick and dirty "hack" for you on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uWUBE/

Hope it helps you out, you could edit it to be more dynamic.
Here is some of the code. It basically loops trough the amount of words and then adds it to a string you assign to a column, I am not a Javascript mastermind at all so.. there might be a better way.

`

```
//  Get the text
var txt = $("p").text();
//  Split every word
var words = txt.split(" ");
//  Count the amount of words
var amount = words.length
//  Amount of columns
var columnAmount = 2

//  Amount of words in first colum 
var firstColumn = Math.floor(amount / columnAmount);

//  String for first column
var firstColumnTxt = "";
//  String for second column
var secondColumnTxt = "";

//  loop trough the words and add them to the first column
for (var i = 0; i < firstColumn; i++){
    firstColumnTxt =     firstColumnTxt + " " + words[i]; 
}
//  loop trough the words and add them to the second column
for (var i = firstColumn; i < amount; i++){
    secondColumnTxt =   secondColumnTxt + " " + words[i];
}

// Add this to your first column
console.log(firstColumnTxt);
//  Add this to your second column
console.log(secondColumnTxt);
```

`

Comment: IThanks! The only thing is I can't use jquery... The assignment's instructions :/ is there anyway I can do this with plain js? I guess I would try it with the same concept, but how would I take care of images and other tags?

Comment: Sorry I just realized only the first line is jquery. I get the algorithm! The only problem is the images and other tags as stated earlier haha

Comment: Ah, I understand. A similar approach could be used with regex I believe, thus matching html tags.. problem is, I don't go well with regex

Comment: Do you have any impact on the data used? If so, you could easily insert a string on which you would split..

Comment: What do you mean impact on the data used? The algorithm needs to be able to work for any body of text with an image, for example.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I thought that if you are able to edit the content via a CMS or something you could add a unique string on which you can split the text. I know what you want to achieve thought, but as said I am unable to provide you such knowledge as I believe it is supposed to be done with regex which I don't master. My best alternative thus was adding a unique string on your content..